# How to make diagonal text starting from character?

Tags: formatting

For the sake of compressing math notes into a more legible form, I'd like to be able to figure out how to put the following in latex; a math formula with extra bits of information written as a diagonal above or below certain characters:

[image]

Is this possible without too much trouble?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes....  (de gustibus non est disputandum)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\rotsup}[1]{\begin{rotate}{45}\tiny ~#1\end{rotate}}

\begin{equation}
    f^{\rotsup{smooth}}: X^{\rotsup{$\in S$}} \to
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```